# Why do I get the same element sizes on different DOM elements using resize directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using this simple directive to know the size (height/width) of an DOM element:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('elementResize', function () {
    'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element ) {

            $scope.getElementDimensions = function () {
               return { 'h': $element.height(), 'w': $element.width() };
            };

            $scope.$watch($scope.getElementDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                $scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
            }, true);
        }]

        };
    });
```

This is the HTML template:

```
<div element-resize>Element1.width:{{windowWidth}}</div><div element-resize>Element2.width:{{windowWidth}}a div with more width space</div>
```

I have two divs that are brothers, but using my directive I get the same sizes of the latest, instead of getting each one of them the real size. What did I missed here?

**UPDATE:**
If I had ng-controller to the first div it will work. Why?

Comment: I have found the problem, but don't really get it: I added ng-controller for every div and now it works. But why I should have seprate controller with nothing in it in order it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use link instead of controller. Here's an example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ytOQlxEf8NN7R0mOPudC?p=preview).

```
app.directive('elementResize', function() {
  'use strict';
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: 'Element.width:{{windowWidth}}',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, ctrl) {
      console.log(element)
      scope.getElementDimensions = function() {
        return {
          'h': element[0].clientHeight,
          'w': element[0].clientWidth
        };
      };

      scope.$watch(scope.getElementDimensions, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
        scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
      }, true);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: 10x, I need it to be updated all the time. The template is being update only on loading

Comment: Is there any good way to use controller and not link with interval?

Comment: As far as I know, controllers are shared between directives. So that's the source of your original problem. I think link is your best option...